# Get updates to telegram channel comments to the message

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

We can get message from user in telegram by `getupdates` api. But for comments in telegram channel message which is introduced by telegram recently I don't get any response. Anyway to do it?

Comment: This future is not implemented yet in bot api.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out...